# I'm getting just one weird row instead 2 normal rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

the problem is i get one weird announcement instead 2 normal announcements (as on my database).

How is looking now (screenshot):

https://prnt.sc/q5q8ju

Code:

```
<?PHP $query = "SELECT * FROM `thbs_announcements` ORDER BY `anno_date` DESC";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                $anno = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
                {
                    while($anno = $result1->fetch_assoc());
                    {
                        if($anno['anno_important'] == 1)
                        {
                            ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-danger">IMPORTANT</span></h2></div><?php
                        }
                        if($anno['anno_important'] != 1)
                        {
                            $today = date("Y-m-d");
                            $dateDiffa = dateDiffInDays($today, $anno['anno_date']);
                            if($dateDiffa < 7 || $dateDiffa > -7)
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-primary">NEW</span></h2></div><?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?></h2></div><?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">No announcements here.</h2></div><?php
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work

```
<?PHP $query = "SELECT * FROM `thbs_announcements` ORDER BY `anno_date` DESC";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
                {
                    while($anno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
                    {
                        if($anno['anno_important'] == 1)
                        {
                            ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-danger">IMPORTANT</span></h2></div><?php
                        }
                        if($anno['anno_important'] != 1)
                        {
                            $today = date("Y-m-d");
                            $dateDiffa = dateDiffInDays($today, $anno['anno_date']);
                            if($dateDiffa < 7 || $dateDiffa > -7)
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-primary">NEW</span></h2></div><?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?></h2></div><?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">No announcements here.</h2></div><?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! Hmm,i don't see anything changed,but is working fine,can you explain how you solved this?

Comment: @NigelRen use this line while($anno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) instead of while($anno = $result1->fetch_assoc());

Comment: You still have `$anno = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` before the loop.  Also please add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: @NigelRen Is not an issues. Issues is ';' end of the while loop line : 6

Comment: So the fact it reads a row and does nothing with it isn't a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
$anno = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

before your loop, so this will effectively discard the first row.  You can just remove this line.

Comment: Same,line deleted

Comment: I mean,i deleted this line,but the problem looks same as in image from question.

Comment: Sure: https://imgur.com/uBU4hYA . - Table: thbs_announcements

Comment: This is an include('content/client_areas/' . $current_client_area . '/announcements.php'),when the user is logged in,the script will use this function.

Do you need the full php script?

Comment: @TopKenzo ';' end of the while loop line

Comment: @TopKenzo use this line while($anno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))  instead of while($anno = $result1->fetch_assoc());

Answer (score 0):

Now is other problem,but in the same code:

```
<?PHP $query = "SELECT * FROM `thbs_announcements` ORDER BY `anno_id` DESC";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
                {
                    while($anno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
                    {
                        if($anno['anno_important'] == 1)
                        {
                            ?><div class="card col-sm-12"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-danger">IMPORTANT</span></h2></div><br><?php
                        }
                        if($anno['anno_important'] != 1)
                        {
                            $today = date("Y-m-d");
                            $dateDiffa = dateDiffInDays($today, $anno['anno_date']);
                            if($dateDiffa < 7 || $dateDiffa > -7)
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?> <span class="badge badge-primary">NEW</span></h2></div><br><?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><?php echo $anno['anno_text'];?></h2></div><br><?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?><div class="card"><h2 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">No announcements here.</h2></div><?php
                }
                ?>
```

Even if the Date difference is more than 7 days i still get NEW on the announcement.

Code for function (dateDiffInDays):

```
function dateDiffInDays($date1, $date2)  
{ 
    $diff = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1); 
    return round($diff / 86400)+1; 
}
```